# Call a function that is defined within $.each

Tags: jquery

I have a function that is defined within an $.each function like below:

```
    var websiteWill;
$.each(cookieConfig.cookies,function(key, value){                                           
            var levelName = key,                                                                     
                websiteWill = function(){
                    alert(this.id);
                    if($('#' + this.id).is(':checked')){
                        $.each(this.value.will,function(){ 
                            $('<li><i class="icon-ok"></i>' + this + '</li>').appendTo(parent  + '-' + levelName + '.will ul');
                        });
                    }
                }
        });
```

When I try to call `websiteWill();` like:

```
$(document).delegate('.cookie-trigger', 'click',function(){
    websiteWill();
});
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

**EDIT:** I have declared the variable as global ^^

Comment: `websiteWill` is local to the `$.each` callback. I don't understand what you are trying to do actually. Maybe if you *explain* what you want to achieve with this code, we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: ^^^ and it's overwritten on each iteration, and never called.

Comment: *" I have declared the variable as global"* Nope. See that `var` in the first line in the callback? That makes the variable local.

Comment: Replace comma after `key` with semicolon and try.

Comment: `EDIT: I have declared the variable as global ^^`. No you havn't. Well you might have, but within that `.each` there you have `var level ...,  websiteWill` meaning, now that variable is in the "scope" of .each, meaning you're not using the global there

Comment: @radium - the function would still be replaced by the next iteration ?

Comment: @adeneo yup, it's rewritten with every loop, but due to the `,` it's only in the scope of that loop, when new loop comes, its *Poof* gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function outside of the local context:

```
var websiteWill = function(element){
    alert(element.id);
    if($('#' + element.id).is(':checked')){
        $.each(element.value.will,function(){ 
            $('<li><i class="icon-ok"></i>' + element + '</li>').appendTo(parent  + '-' + levelName + '.will ul');
        });
    }
};
```

(Note that I replaced references to `this` with references to a function argument called `element`, which you can call something else if you'd like.)

Then you can reference it from your call to `delegate()`:

```
$(document).delegate('.cookie-trigger', 'click', function(){
    websiteWill(this);
});
```

You could also reference it within that original call to `each()`, but you don't actually *do* anything in that call so I'm not sure what the purpose would be for that.

Answer (score 0):

What Felix Kling said is right; you're declaring the function inside of the .each callback function, which makes it local to that function only. If you want it accessible outside of that you'd need to write it as a function outside of that .each somehow, and then use that new function inside the .each loop you have there. for instance write the function like:

```
var websiteWill = function(id, value){
// code here
}
```

And then call that inside the .each

```
$(document).delegate('.cookie-trigger', 'click', websiteWill(id, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code
create a method `fnwebsiteWill`

```
function fnwebsiteWill(ctrl) {
                var $this = ctrl;
                alert($this.id);
                if ($('#' + $this.id).is(':checked')) {
                    $.each($this.value.will, function () {
                        $('<li><i class="icon-ok"></i>' + $this + '</li>').appendTo(parent + '-' + levelName + '.will ul');
                    });
                }
            }
```

fnwebsiteWill is the one which you used into .each

```
var websiteWill;
        $.each(cookieConfig.cookies, function (key, value) {
            var levelName = key,
                websiteWill = fnwebsiteWill(this);
        });
```

Again call the same function into delegate

```
  $(document).delegate('.cookie-trigger', 'click', function () {
            fnwebsiteWill(this);
        });
```

Comment: Code without explanation is rarely helpful. Please explain what you have changed and how it solves the problem.